# Adjust Docking in Panel with Grid and Form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a parent container panel that contains a :

Form :Usercontrol (Just has buttons to navigate the documents viewer)
Grid : Documentsviewer

This parent container panel is docked on the Left of the screen (right is for document preview)

How can i make the Grid to occupy about 80% Of the available left space, while the Form has about 20% ?

Not matter what i do like setting the dockstyle to Top for the Grid and Bottom for the second, the size of the form is almost as large as the grid. Even changing the size of the form in properties doesn't make any changes. Also Autosize is disabled for both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you need control layout with percentage in windows forms, [`TableLayoutPanel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21wykkx(v=vs.110).aspx) is a good option.
You can use a `TableLayoutPanel` with 1 row and 2 columns and set column 1 width to 20% and column 2 width to 80%. Then you can put your desired controls to its cells and set `Dock` property of those controls to `Fill`.

You can configure rows and columns using `RowCount`, `ColumnCount`, `Rows` and `Columns` properties.

Comment: Works as expected, Thanks !